# asp.net membership/roles provider question

Tags: asp.net, roles, provider

My application needs the ability to be secured at different levels for different teams.  For example, someone may be an administrator for one team but may only be a viewer for another.

Ideally I'd like to have a single, small set of roles, but I'd like to assign people to separate roles per teams.  i.e. "Joe" might be an administrator for TeamA but have Reader access for TeamB.

Will the Asp.Net provider framework support this?

--Matt

Update:  My issue is with the "IsInRole" method.  It takes a single parameter.  Other than hacking it (concatenating two items together, like the team ID and the role name) is there any other way to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there are no groups to roles in terms of how the [`RoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) class works, but there's no reason why you couldn't implement a grouping structure in your datasource. The RoleProvider does support different application names however, so it may be possible to use this to come up with some way of segmenting an application in to logical groups that are identified as being different and thus having different roles assigned to them.

**EDIT:**

In response to your edit, you could have the structure as follows in your database

```
Group Table           Access Table           Role Table
id | name             id | name              group_id | access_id | name
-----------           ------------           ---------------------------
1    Team A           1    Guest              1          1         Team A Guest
2    Team B           2    User               1          2         Team A User
                      3    Admin              1          3         Team A Admin
```

an have a mechanism for updating the `name` field in the `Role` table when a new row is inserted.

Implementing a custom RoleProvider is very straightforward. You simply need to inherit from `RoleProvider` and override the methods that you need, writing the logic for where the RoleProvider should get the data from.

Comment: Thanks Russ, that DB structure is similar to the one I was thinking I'd have to use.  One problem I'm having though is what the caller will pass to IsInRole.  The single parameter (role name) may not work for me.  (I've actually oversimplified my question, there's also a hierarchical structure to teams).  Anyway, thanks for the input. I think this (or something similar) will be the route I go.

---Matt

Comment: @Matt - the name that would be passed in would be the name in the RoleTable i.e. if (User.IsInRole("Team A Guest")).

Comment: thanks again Russ.  That was my thought as well (concatenating the name). I think I can make it work but it feels hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Not straight out of the box. You would need to create a custom provider to support this functionality

here is an example of creating a custom membership provider
http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-189.aspx

Comment: See the comment I added to the main question above, regarding the "IsInRole" method.

Comment: Microsoft designed it so that you could create your own role provider as well. Create your own class by first inheriting from the RoleProvider and then provide methods that would take the team id, and then the role name

Comment: you would basically have to write the sql that would do the check